# Unable to generate a parameterized URL to a controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have following route defined:

```
Route::get('details/{exchangeID?}', function($exchangeID = 0)
{
    return App::make('Exchange')->details($exchangeID);
});
```

And I am doing following to generate a URL

```
{{ URL::action('Exchange@details', array('1')) }}
```

Which throws Invalid Argument Exception with Message:

```
Unknown action [Exchange@details].
```

What's wrong here?

I am on Laravel 4

Answer (score 0):

I think in my case the only way to do it is:

```
 {{ URL::to('details', array('1')); }}
```

If someone has better approach then do share.